# WordPress help needed - Home and Blogs post not loading correctly

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this website [TheCodeGene](http://thecodegene.com)

After loading a collection of button designs in Divi library, website stopped working correctly.

At first Home page and none of the blog post pages was not loading only the header.

I changed for the memory to 256M, now it is loading, however everything is messed up.

Everything is up to date, no new plugins added.

[Update]

I fixed the Homepage by deleting the Blog post slider. Now checking all the blog posts for errors.

Any ideas??

Comment: Disable all previously add plugin and then check.

Comment: Anything in the server's PHP logs?

Comment: Hi Syed, already done that, and all the basic troubleshooting, nothing worked.

Comment: @Hobo, didn't see anything, I'll double check. It's weird that only the Home page and the Blog is not working. All the rest are working just fine.

Comment: I can see the home page (in chrome).  There seems to be a problem with the slideshow code (not sure if it's a plugin or in your theme) - each post is repeated many times, and some of the tags aren't closed correctly

Answer (score -1):

After @Hobo mentioned that there is something with the slide code, I started checking all the slides and it looks like the post slider was creating all the issues.

Got rid of it, everything working as expected now.

Cheers,
Radu